# Django unitTest response.content doesnt show proper user info

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-testing

I am facing the following problem. When I am running a unit test to verify whether user logged in properly, returned HTTP response doesn't contain variables from the template.

```
class WorkflowViewTest(TestCase):

    def test_response_authorized(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.get(username='JohnDoe')

        self.client.force_login(user)
        response = self.client.get('/workflow/')

        print(response.content.decode()) # response content is not right

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) # assertions are passing just fine
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'workflow.html')
```

Simplified content of used template `'workflow.html'` is:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% if user %}
{{user}}
{{user.username}}
{{user.first_name}}
{{user.last_name}}
{{user.email}}

{% else %}

User variable not provided

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Where encoded `response.context.content` is following:

```
<body>

AnonymousUser





</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to create a user within setUp of the test, I also created user manually, I tried both `self.client.force_login()` and `self.client.login()`. None of the proposed solutions I found were working.

I really appreciate any insight. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not realize that I changed in `settings.py` default `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to my company backend. For testing behavior of application without the user really logging in, I had to additionally to above changes also `@modify_settings` or create test_setting as bellow:

```
@modify_settings(AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS={'remove': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
                                          'append': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'})
class WorkflowViewTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
```